# How to click an element with Selenium webdriver javascript?

Tags: node.js, selenium, selenium-webdriver, onclick, click

I am testing, and I have to click on elements, but it sometimes click, sometimes not. I tried some solutions, but there is no one, which always clicks.
Is there any solution to click an element, which always works?

I tried these codes:

1:

```
await driver.findElement(By.id("u_0_a")).click();
```

2:

```
var element = await driver.findElement(By.id("u_0_a"));
await element.click();
```

3:

```
await driver.executeScript("document.getElementById('u_0_a').click()");
```

I use selenium with node.js, javascript, chrome driver.

Comment: The `click()` function in JavaScript does not execute any "click" event handlers.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for your help. The problem was not in my code. The problem was with the https://www.facebook.com/ .
Because facebook, is changing the ID, and sometimes it was the login button sometimes a gender custom button. :/

Answer (score 2):

Try using:

```
var element = await driver.findElement(By.id("u_0_a"));
await driver.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", element)
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for help, but it is the same :( Sometimes click, sometimes not. :(

Answer (score 0):

Try using `TryUntil`. I hope this works. The below code is in C#

```
Browser.TryUntil(() => { }, () => Browser.FindElement(By.id("u_0_a")).Exists(), TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3), TimeSpan.FromSeconds(120));
Browser.FindElement(By.id("u_0_a")).Click();
```

Comment: Well it is C#, but I try to write it in JS.

Answer (score -1):

Please try sleep before you handle the click operation.
Example as below:

```
await driver.sleep(2000)
await driver.findElement(By.xpath('element path')).click()
```

Comment: generally using sleep should be considered the final option.  Incorporating sleeps into your test will slowly make your test extremely sleep and very difficult to run.